# Generic type to dynamically set key in an object

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have two typescript types that I would like to combine into one generic type:

```
type WordTimestamps = {
  timestamps: {start: number, end: number},
  word: string
}

type SentenceTimestamps = {
  timestamps: {start: number, end: number},
  sentence: string
}
```

The only difference between them is the second key, so I want to come up with a single generic type which I imagine should be called as something like `Timestamps<'word'>` for the former and `Timestamps<'sentence'>` for the latter.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've only come up with the code below, which doesn't do it.

```
type Timestamps<T> = {
  timestamps: { start: number; end: number };
  [key: T]: string;
};
```

Comment: I suspect there's a clever way to do this, but I also suspect it will be awkward to work with in practice. Maybe `type TimestampBase = { timestamps: {start: number; end: number; } };` and then use `TimestampBase & {word: string}` and `TimestampBase & {sentence: string}`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a combination using [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) might be suitable :

```
type TimestampBase = { timestamps: {start: number, end: number} };

type TimestampKeys = 'word' | 'sentence';

type Timestamp<T extends TimestampKeys> = TimestampBase & Pick<Record<T, string>, T>;

const word: Timestamp<'word'> = {
  timestamps: { start: 0, end: 0 },
  word: 'word'
};

const sentence: Timestamp<'sentence'> = {
  timestamps: { start: 0, end: 0 },
  sentence: 'sentence'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type Keys = 'word' | 'sentence';

type Timestamp = {
    timestamps: { start: number, end: number }
}

type Timestamps<T> = T extends string ? Record<T, string> & Timestamp : never


// (Record<"word", string> & Timestamp) | (Record<"sentence", string> & Timestamp)

type WordTimestamps = Timestamps<Keys>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHIDuB7ATgEzSgB90EIA7YCgYwjQG4AoR0SKAFQEsBbCBYAIbcwKKAG9GUKVGA8%20g4QgBc4qPwE5gK8gFduAIwg4ANFAp5tewzigBfRvZbhoXXusUAedgD5R7MwAeVOR4SPw4nOQA5lAA-FAAShDUuHhepuGRUb4AZBxy7iLaEABuRsyMAPSVUAAUSSn4HgBE2PjNGcAR0bn5bgpgAJTEdQ2pLWSUNBAdal1Zva7yQkPMrNAA6qlLhUioOwMIHnCI3sxAA)

You can add any allowed property name to `Keys`. It will be automatically distributed.

`T extends string ?` - makes sure that union type will be distributet over  `Record<T, string>`